creating an app in android studio where i can send a mass notification from the host device to all devices
I am creating an app in android studio that should allow alerts to be sent from the main users device to all other devices.
Ideally i would like to incorporate a seen function to show who has seen the notification
I have tried using push notifications in the app but I think I may need to host this on a server, looking for suggestions

"I think I may need to host this on a server" -- you will need that for just about any solution. Your "seen" information has to be stored somewhere centrally.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
